# How can I create a menu?

Tags: android

I want to create a menu. What is my problem? I think is true but it doesn't work. I don't want to use boolean.

```
onCreateOptionsMenu(menu){
  menu.add(1, 1, 1, "setting").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage);  
}
onOptionsItemSelected(item){
  switch(item.getItemId()){
    case 1:
      Intent move=new Intent(Activity_main.this,Activity_main2.class);
      startActivity(move);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please try to make your question as specific as possible. I have formatted your code sample for you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `true` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` to indicate "Yes, I want to show menu". Don't forget to call through to super.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(1, 1, 1, "setting").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage);  
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're not even trying. **1)** What error? **2)** You don't just copy another man's code without understanding it first. My syntax differs a little from yours so we're either using a different language or you didn't copy code properly. Now my language is Java and yours looks close enough, so I expect you to translate it. **3)** This is not how you usually create menus. Google "android inflate menu".